# How to use valgrind's massif-out-file option correctly?

Tags: valgrind, massif

When running `valgrind --tool=massif benchmark1 --massif-out-file=test.out` on MacOS (10.12.6) with version `valgrind-3.13.0`, output is produced, but only in the default filename format, i.e. `massif.out.\d+`. No `test.out` file is generated. Exemplary output is:

```
==32233== Massif, a heap profiler
==32233== Copyright (C) 2003-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Nicholas Nethercote
==32233== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==32233== Command: benchmark1 --massif-out-file=./test.out
==32233==
```

What am I missing, or is this feature ignored for the MacOS version? I tried also to put the file name in quotes with no success.

Answer (score 4):

According to the trace above, you have given the valgrind --massif-out-file=./test.out
option to benchmark1, which has probably silently ignored it.

You have to do:

```
   valgrind ...valgrind options...   your_program ....your program options....
```

So, try something like:

```
valgrind --tool=massif --massif-out-file=./test.out benchmark1
```

Answer (score 1):

After working with some valgrind tools (memcheck and massif), I found that we must follow follow it's rule:

```
valgrind --tool=... valgrind_option=... your_program program_argument
```